# error al subir imagen a base de datos SQL SERVER desde ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, imagen

Buenas estoy teniendo problemas al subir una imagen a la base de datos sql server, tengo un campo de tipo imagen en la base de datos lo que quiero es capturar la imagen y convertirla a base 64 para guardarla en la BD

[image: Captura de la base de datos]

desde el controlador tengo el siguiente codigo

```
public ActionResult Create(Models.ItemModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    JoyeriaEntities contexto = new JoyeriaEntities();


                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageData"];
                    byte[] img = ConvertToBytes(file);

                    Items items = new Items
                    {
                        IdItem = model.IdItem,
                        Nombre = model.Nombre,
                        IdKMaterial = model.IdKMaterial,
                        Costo = model.Costo,
                        Precio = model.Precio,
                        Image = img
                    };               
                    contexto.Items.Add(items);
                    contexto.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    return View(model);
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Este es el método que utilizo para convertir la imagen a bytes

```
 public byte[] ConvertToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            byte[] imageBytes = null;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream);
            imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)image.ContentLength);
            return imageBytes;
        }
```

este seria el codigo del modelo

```
namespace JoyeriaE.Models
{
    public class ItemModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdItem { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requerido")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requerido")]
        public int Precio { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requerido")]     
        public int Costo { get; set; }


        //Valores del kilate de la pieza
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requerido")]
        [MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "El valor no puede tener más de 1 caracteres")]
        public int IdKMaterial { get; set; }
        public string Kilate { get; set; }
        //fin de los valores

        [AllowHtml]
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }


    }
```

y este seria el código de la vista

```
        <div class="form-group">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Content", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" onchange="fileCheck(this);" />
                }


                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

ahora bien cuando trato de crear un nuevo item me tira un error de que no se puede convertir un objeto de tipo in32 a Array
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nos muestras  el código de tu modelo? De acuerdo a la excepción, parece que el problema está en los data annotations...

Comment: @Arriel Listo ya agregue el codigo del modelo, muchas gracias !

Comment: 1. En la base de datos, la imagen, no se guarda en base64, se guardan los bytes de la imagen como tal. Si estás recién creando la base de datos, no uses el tipo `image`, ese está marcado como obsoleto por Microsoft hace muchos años. Utiliza el tipo `varbinary(max)`, que es la recomendación del fabricante.

Comment: Entendido muchas gracias !